# Cannot successsfully parse mysql database info

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-workbench, wampserver

I'm trying to call a procedure in a module that needs some arguments, thus:

`MySQL code to be executed (extracted from the module's procedure):`

```
Sub InsertRecord(ByVal tbl As String, ByVal cols() As String, ByVal params() As String, ByVal colCondition As String, ByVal paramCondition As String) 'As String

                :
                :

    comA.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " & tbl & " (" & newCols & ") SELECT * FROM (SELECT @params) AS tmp "
    comA.CommandText &= "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT " & newCols & " FROM " & tbl & " WHERE " & colCondition & " = @param) limit 1"
    comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", paramCondition)
    comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@params", newParams)

                :
                :

End Sub
```

`Call Code:`

```
    myModule.SaveInfo("myprod", {"col_a", "col_b", "col_c", "col_d", "col_e", "col_f", "col_g", "col_h"}, _
                            {val_a, val_b, val_c, val_d, val_e, val_f, val_g, val_h}, "col_b", val_b)
```

hint: `newCols` and `newParams` (obtained from `cols()` and `params()` respectively) are comma-delineated lists of columns of the table in question and values to be inserted respectively.

When i run my code, i get the error: `column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Please how do i address this issue? I've been on it for some days now.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I decided to write the code on the sub, instead of using a module. Here is the full subroutine:

```
 Private Sub SaveProduct(ByVal p_code As String, ByVal b_id As String, ByVal m_id As String, _
                        ByVal c_id As String, ByVal des As String, ByVal o_det As String) 
    'modNewData.InsertRecord("products", {"prd_code", "brnd_id", "mnu_id", "cat_id", "prd_description", "prd_details", "prd_create_date", "prd_last_update"}, _
    '                        {p_code, b_id, m_id, c_id, des, o_det, Date.Now.ToShortDateString, Date.Now.ToShortDateString}, "brnd_id", b_id)

    con = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=inventory_db; Uid=root; Pwd=;")
    comA = New MySqlCommand

    'INSERT NEW RECORD.
    comA.CommandText = "INSERT INTO products (prd_code, brnd_id, mnu_id, cat_id, prd_description, prd_details, prd_create_date, prd_last_update) "
    comA.CommandText &= "SELECT * FROM (SELECT @params) AS tmp "
    comA.CommandText &= "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT prd_code, brnd_id, mnu_id, cat_id, prd_description, prd_details, prd_create_date, prd_last_update FROM products "
    comA.CommandText &= "WHERE brnd_id = @param) limit 1"
    comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", b_id)
    comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@params", {p_code, b_id, m_id, c_id, des, o_det, Date.Now.ToShortDateString, Date.Now.ToShortDateString})
    comA.Connection = con

    con.Open()
    comA.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

    'Release used up components
    comA.Parameters.Clear()
    comA.Dispose()
    comA = Nothing
    con = Nothing

    MsgBox("done.")
```

At this point, i don't seem to know what i'm doing, but I know what i want to achieve - insert a new record in a table. **I strongly believe that there's a problem with my sql code, but can't figure out exactly what it is.** Your help is highly needed at this point. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 2:**
I tweaked the `mysql insert code` above, and now i can successfully insert new record to my table. But one more problem exists: I get this `<Unable to read data>` error in my `datetime` and `timestamp` columns respectively.

```
id  prd_code    brnd_id    mnu_id   cat_id  desc       details    create_date (datetime)    last_update(timestamp)
10  PM-16326    10         9        6       Red        NULL       10/15/2013 8:22:00 AM     7/16/2015 9:13:03 AM
17  PM-55326    23         28       11      Olive oil  n/a        <Unable to read data>     <Unable to read data>
```

Here's the new insert code:

```
    'INSERT NEW RECORD.
    comA.CommandText = "INSERT INTO products (prd_code, brnd_id, mnu_id, cat_id, prd_description, prd_details, prd_create_date, prd_last_update) "
    comA.CommandText &= "SELECT * FROM (SELECT @p_code, @b_id, @m_id, @c_id, @des, @o_det, '11/11/2015 9:00:00 AM', '11/12/2015 9:00:00 AM') AS tmp "
    comA.CommandText &= "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT prd_code, brnd_id, mnu_id, cat_id, prd_description, prd_details, prd_create_date, prd_last_update FROM products "
    comA.CommandText &= "WHERE brnd_id = @b_id) limit 1"
    comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_code", p_code)
    comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b_id", b_id)
    comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m_id", m_id)
    comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_id", c_id)
    comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@des", des)
    comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@o_det", o_det)
```

If i replaced the two dates above with `date.now.tostring`, I'll get the error: `you have repeated columns...`
I really need your help guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The columns you pass to the procedure (which *do* match) are called `cols`, but in the query you use `newCols`.

The MySQL error you get means that the values you insert are not in the same number as the columns you say they should fill: you cannot insert four values into five columns, or three.

So what is happening is clearly that you do *something* to retrieve `newCols` from `cols`, in the part of code you have omitted. Probably, depending on some condition, you add some columns (or leave some out). That is what is causing your trouble. You should modify at the same time, apparently, the value of `params` into some other value, possibly `newParams`.

Also, perhaps the condition is not always true, and you observe the function misbehaving only occasionally, or passing some test (because that test does not trigger the column-modifying bug).

Comment: @Iserni, thanks for the reply. I actually used a for...each loop to get each string in the parsed array, then separated them by a comma, as explained earlier. Then i used a msgbox, somewhere in the loop to confirm that both the columns and the values that i extracted from the arrays are the same in number (i.e 8 columns & 8 values). Here's my code:   `Dim myCols As String = "" For Each col As String In cols myCols &= col & ", " Next Dim newCols As String = myCols.Remove(myCols.Count - 2, 2) 'MsgBox(newCols)`